# I'm trying to access a public property from a different form however I can't seem to access it in the second form

Tags: c#, forms, properties

In my main form I have a property being set:

**Main Form:**

```
Int32 _pid1;
public Int32 pid1
{
    get { return _pid1; }
    set { _pid1 = value; }
}
```

On a button click, I open a new form, pass the main form as a constructor parameter like this:

```
private void admin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    adminSettings adminW = new adminSettings(this);
    //adminW.ShowDialog();
}
```

In my second form, I try to access the property like this:

```
public adminSettings(Form mains)
{
    temp = mains.pid1;
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

In VS I can't compile because it highlights the property and shows error:

> 'System.Windows.Forms.Form' does not contain a definition for
>   'pid1' and no extension method 'pid1' accepting a first argument of
>   type 'System.Windows.Forms.Form' could be found (are you missing a
>   using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)   D:\UI_still_in_progress\user_interface\Admin_screen.cs  67  25  user_interface

Intellisense also doesn't pick up on it. I've explored stackoverflow for an answer but so far it seems I've done everything correct. I'm at a loss here, any help would be much appreciated.

**Edit 1:**

This is where I have declared the properties in the main form:

```
public partial class mainForm : Form
{
    //constructor
    public mainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //Add game titles here - The text must be referenced later in order to change game directory for exe file
        this.gameSelect.Items.Add("Bumblebee Game");
        this.gameSelect.Items.Add("Flight Simulator");
        this.gameSelect.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;  //read only    
        this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle;
        this.MinimizeBox = false;
        this.MaximizeBox = false;
    }

    //properties
    Int32 _pid1;
    public Int32 pid1
    {
        get { return _pid1; }
        set { _pid1 = value; }
    }

    Int32 _did1;
    public Int32 did1
    {
        get { return _did1; }
        set { _did1 = value; }
    }

    Int32 _sid1;
    public Int32 sid1
    {
        get { return _sid1; }
        set { _sid1 = value; }
    }

    private void admin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        adminSettings adminW = new adminSettings(newLoginRequest, this);
        //adminW.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

Comment: did1, do you mean pid1?

Comment: The name of the variable is pid1 not did1. please change and see.

Comment: sorry, spelling mistake when copying over. issue still there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are casting your MainForm to a basic Windows Form which will not have your property. Cast it to the class name of your main form in your adminSettings constructor.

```
public adminSettings(Form1 mains)
{
    temp = mains.did1;
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

This assumes that your MainForm's class is Form1